# Excel web app (sharepoint) - active cell when open workbook

Tags: excel, sharepoint

I wrote a program that makes an Excel file.

When I view the output file in my local Excel it opens on a column that I made active in the code:

`Application.ActiveWindow.ScrollColumn = 40;`

But in when upload the file to SharePoint (2010&2013) it opens on the **first** column.

Any idea why?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

finally I found a workaround: 
link to the Excel file and add the cell you want: 
`[Server_name]/_layouts/xlviewer.aspx?id=http://Shared%20Documents/…`